# Calculating probabilities of single events given intersections

Tags: probability

It is given that the sample space is $\{a,b,c\}$, with

- $P(\{a,b\})=0.7$,
- $P(\{b,c\})=0.6$.

I am asked to find the probabilities of $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$ and $\{c\}$. It seems very trivial but I am not sure of where to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you let A, B, and C represent the individual probabilities of the respective elements you already have two equations that these three variables satisfy:

```
A + B = 0.7
B + C = 0.6
```

There's another equation that they must satisfy because a, b, and c are the only things that can happen. I'll let you figure that one out on your own, but once you find it you should be able to solve three equations in three unknows.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. I was thinking that the equations should have the probabilities multiplying instead of adding. Thank you for the input. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  It seems you are to assume that exactly one of $a,b,c$ happens.  Then the first gives you $P(a)+P(b)=0.7$  You should be able to write two more equations and solve the three equations for the three unknowns.